# How can I print more than one line of a file using python?

Tags: python, file-io, input, io

Whenever I try to read files using my python program, I only get one line before the command stops. I'm pretty sure that it has to do with `print(line)` but I don't know any other options. Here's what I have so far:

```
def fopen():
    file = input("Open: ")
    print("")
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
            print("")
            editredirect()

def editredirect():
    print("You can edit this file with the 'edit' command.")
    dcmdLvl2()
```

dcmdLcl2() is just to send me back to my command line.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this. What does `dcmdLvl2` do?

Comment: What does `editredirect()` do?

Comment: I think you need to unindent `editredirect()` to align with `with`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to print `"You can edit this file..."` for *every* line in the file? Probably not...

Also, if `dcmdLvl2()` quits the script for whatever reason, then yeah, you'd only see one line of your file.

Try un-indenting `editredirect()`

```
def fopen():
    file = input("Open: ")
    print("")
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
            print("")   # new line?
    editredirect()

def editredirect():
    print("You can edit this file with the 'edit' command.")
    dcmdLvl2()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `editredirect()` is inside a loop because of indent.
Try to remove indent and move `editredirect()` (and probably `print("")`) out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You redirect to command line after reading one line, you should remove `editredirect` from `for` loop:

```
def fopen():
   file = input("Open: ")
   print("")
   with open(file, 'r') as f:
      for line in f:
          print(line)
          print("")
   editredirect()
```